# Can't use icon in trigger button for modal window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

hello I have a problem with the modal window trigger button. If I put an icon in it I can't click on the button. What should I do?

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_help" 
        class="btn btn-inverse" title="Help">
    <i class="icon-question-sign icon-white"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: did you try it with anchor tag, bootstrap buttons work with `<a></a>` anchor tag.

Comment: Are you sure you have modal with id of ``modal_help``. because it's working for me.

Comment: the title is hilarious, almost impossible to read aloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fubys/)

```
 <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_help" class="btn btn-inverse" title="Help">
  <i class="icon-question-sign icon-white"></i>
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal_help" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have to add `bootstrap.css`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css"/>
```

And both `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js`

```
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast help, I found the problem through you. The official example doesn't use the hide class and the modal was not hidden and went over the navbar, and the buttons were not accessible. so the use of the hide class resolved my problem. Thank you.